# select distinct from dataset

Tags: datatable, dataset, datarow

I have got duplicate rows in a dataset. how can i select distinct rows from that.

From comments: My query is something like this:

```
select name, age 
from student
```

When I receive its output in a dataset the output consists of rows having duplicate names. Using dataset itself I have to select distinct name from this because I need the same query with duplicate values for some other place.

Comment: What's the query you're using?

Comment: Need a lot more detail - is this in SQL?  Your tags tend to make me think it's actually in .NET using a `DataTable` but you have no detail provided so it's impossible to tell

Comment: Hey guys, don't downvote. Let him know the question is borked and ask him to fix it; if he _doesn't_ fix it, then downvote him....

Comment: @Michael: I'll remove the down-vote *when* he fixes it. Down-votes are there to discourage bad questions.

Comment: @skaffman I understand, but a downvote with no comment to a new user only confuses, not discourages.

Comment: i will clear my question. my query is like for eg: select name, age from student. and i receive its output in a dataset. output consist rows having duplicate name. using dataset itself i have to select distinct name from this because i need the same query with duplicate values for some other place

Answer (score 1):

```
 select DISTINCT name, age from student
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need both the distinct data as well as the full data (with duplicate values), then you'll either have to maintain two datasets or continue doing things as you are now.